# Wicket Panel not refreshed when swapped in via an AJAX request

Tags: ajax, wicket

I have a Panel that I initially replace with another panel (a spinning circle saying "loading") and after a while in an AJAX event replace back. So what I do is:

```
@Override
protected void onConfigure() {
    if (!content.isLoaded()) {
        tmp = new LoadingCircle(getId(), "Loading...");
        this.replaceWith(tmp);
    }
}

public void onLoaded(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
    if (tmp != null) {
        tmp.replaceWith(this);
        tmp = null;
    }
    target.add(this);
}
```

This works, so the panel is shown back in the page. However, this panel has some subpanels with some labels and they are not refreshed. I see the updated labels when I reload the page but not immediately after showing the whole panel with AJAX.

I notice that the `onConfigure` and `onBeforeRender` methods are called only once - when the panel is created but not again when it is actually shown for the first time using AJAX. The same for the subpanels, so that would explain why they are not refreshed. But the question is - why is the panel not refreshed (the updated model values are not used) when it is added to the AJAX request target?

EDIT: I think this may be relevant: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-5107. Still, I wonder what I should change in my code to make it work?

Comment: For one, why not use an AjaxLazyLoadPanel? It seems to me that does exactly what you want.

If WICKET-5107 is indeed relevant than it should be that some components are not visible. Can you give more sample code from your application?

Comment: Apologies for my late response. AjaxLazyLoadPanel looks like the way to go, I didn't know about it! Thanks.

Comment: In the end I just changed the logic of this piece of application so that the panel did not need to be replaced. (Should I put this as the answer or somehow otherwise close the question?)

Answer (score -1):

IMO it looks like you should use an AjaxCallDecorator instead to do what you are trying to do with the spinner.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the advice, although it is not clear to me how I should use AjaxCallDecorator in my case?